# INSERT INTO SELECT syntax error Python ODBC with Microsoft Access

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, insert

Had a long search through here and the web and can't seem to find any examples that explain why I am getting a syntax error on the following:
import win32com.client

```
`
        PregCode = recordsetraw.Fields.Item("PregnancyCode").value
        SQL = "INSERT INTO UniqueData SELECT * FROM Rawdata WHERE PregnancyCode =%s"
        params = (PregCode)
        connection.execute(SQL, params)
        print PregCode
    recordsetraw.MoveNext()`
```

I'm getting the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testdb.py", line 22, in 
    connection.execute(SQL, params)
  File "", line 2, in execute
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft JET D
atabase Engine', u"Syntax error in query expression 'PregnancyCode = %s'.", None
, 5003000, -2147217900), None)

I have tried hardcoding in PregnancyCode to see if that would make a difference but no, same error.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The 2nd argument to `execute()` needs to be a sequence. As written it is a single value. Use instead `(PregCode,)`; note trailing comma. The comma makes it a tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Python is very rusty, and I don't recall what this type of substitution is called, but I think you're trying to accomplish something similar to this with your INSERT statement:

```
>>> print "Hello %s" %("World")
Hello World
```

From your code:

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO UniqueData SELECT * FROM Rawdata WHERE PregnancyCode =%s"
params = (PregCode)
connection.execute(SQL, params)
```

Trouble is *connection* is an ADO Connection, and its [Execute Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675023%28VS.85%29.aspx) won't perform the Pythonic text substitution you want.

I think you should do the text substitution in Python **before** you feed the INSERT string to `connection.execute`  Maybe something like this:

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO UniqueData SELECT * FROM Rawdata WHERE PregnancyCode =%s" %(PregCode)
connection.execute(SQL)
```

If I didn't get the Python quite right, hopefully it's close enough so you can see how to fix it.

BTW, your title mentions Python ODBC, but I don't see that your code uses ODBC at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL needs an "INTO" clause:

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO UniqueData SELECT * FROM Rawdata WHERE PregnancyCode =%s"
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, had an INTO in there, and I still get an error.